# Real constants in a polynomial spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}[x]_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]_4$ defined as $T(p(x)) = p'(x)$. Quite clearly any $p \in \text{Im}(T)$ is of the general form

$$T(a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_4x^4) = a_1 + 2a_2x +3a_3x^2 +4a_4x^3$$

Hence

$$\text{Im}(T) = \text{span}\Big\{x^0, 2x, 3x^2, 4x^3 \Big \}$$

Of course, $x^0 \in \mathbb{R}[x]_4$ is simply $1 \in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, depending on whether how one "thinks of" $x^0$, one falls over the real space or over the real polynomial space. Since any $p$ in the range of $T$ must be spanned by polynomial vectors $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]_4$, the presence of $x^0 = 1$ in the spanning set of said range makes me uneasy.

It is of course entirely natural for an element to be a member of multiple sets ($1$ is a member of $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}[x]_k, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{N}, ...$). However, I wanted to ask here whether this spanning set is correct for the range of $T$, and whether real constants are proper elements of polynomial spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spanning set is correct. You should verify that if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R^*}$, then $span\{a,bx,cx^2,dx^3\} = \mathbb{R}[x]_3$

And yes, any real number is an element of $\mathbb{R}[x]_k$ for any $k$.

For example, $7 \in \mathbb{R}[x]_5$ since we can write:

$7 = 7 + 0x+0x^2+0x^3+0x^4+0x^5$

Comment: Much to the point. Thank you for your answer!